# How to wire garage door sensors

Tags: doors, garage

The wiring to my garage door sensors has gone bad basically right at the point it gets to the connector at the end of the wire. It's an older Sears model that they no longer sell parts for (model 13953628SRT).

I bought the recommended bell wire but the wire itself lacks the small white plastic connectors use to connect the wire to the remote sensor.

Can I buy these connectors to crimp on somewhere or buy bell wire that has them already? I've been searching with no luck but maybe that's because I don't really know what to call the connectors I'm looking for???!

UPDATE: Added images below:

Connector:
[1]:
[image]

Connects to 2 small pins:
[image]

Comment: We don't know what to call them either because we can't see them. How about a photo? Do the sensors open with screws? I'd probably be doing some soldering to add connector pigtails of my choosing, but hard to say without details.

Comment: I'd also check for compatible brands. "Older model" isn't very descriptive, but far enough back they were often interchangeable. Again, details please.

Comment: Connectors are for convenience.. if you're determined you can eliminate them and join by other means -- solder, probably.

Comment: Added pics above. 

Model is 13953628SRT. Its a Craftsman brand from Sears. It's at least 13 years old but I have no idea how much older it is than that.

Comment: Given that its just two pins sticking out of the back of the remote sensor, I think it would be difficult to connect them in any other way than having a connector.

Comment: Can you post pictures of the other sides of that connector? I'm interested in seeing the wires, how they go into the connector and especially the spot where it's broken...

Comment: Close up pics are good, but not when they're so close that the camera can't focus. Back off just a smidge with any other pics you may add so that things are more in focus - that really helps people see what's going on, and especially to read writing that may be included.

Comment: There's nothing visibly broken... if you move the wire though you can see the light on the laser go one and off. 

The connector itself is pretty small, like the size of a pencil eraser, hence why the pics are so close. The bad spot in the wire is too close to the connector to splice in wire any closer than I already have and have enough wire left to reuse the connectors. I tried splicing in wire further down but it didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a search for female crimp connector. You probably don't need the plastic connector if you have two pins sticking out of the sensor. You can connect the wires to the crimp connector (you just squeeze the connector with pliers around the stripped wire) and then the crimp connector to each pin separately. You can wrap them with electrical tape or heat shrink tubing if they're close together. You may find some used connectors on ebay, search for Chamberlain or Liftmaster the opener is actually made by Chamberlain, finding anything for Sears is more difficult now. You can also buy a new set of sensors with the wires already connected. Hard to tell from the photo how big the pins are.

[image: crimp connectors]

Comment: Unless you have really strong and really small fingers, a pair of needle nose pliers may become necessary to plug/unplug these once the white plastic housing. And, excellent point about Chamberlain/LiftMaster/Crafstman all being one brand now.

Comment: Thanks! I order some of these off Amazon since I couldn't find them local (RIP Radio Shack). I'm hoping their small enough because the bell wire and the connectors are pretty small.

If that doesn't work I may have to try and order so a full set of lasers. For some reason they don't like to sell the wires alone, just with a set of the lasers (so $60+).

Comment: If the Amazon ones are too big an auto parts store might have smaller ones.

Comment: I tried hard w/ connectors that look like the ones in the pic above but the area I was connecting to was really small and rectangle shaped and crimp as I tried, I just couldn't get a good connection that gripped to the metal pegs and stayed there at all. 

I was at fleet farm looking for something else and saw a set of Chamberlain sensors for $20 less than online and I bought those and replaced my old sensors. Working good now.